# WPF DataTrigger throwing warning only in designer when in another assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm setting a data template for a combobox item used in my RCTComboBox class and it works fine at runtime, but when in the designer in another assembly it will throw a warning and fail to show its contents. The warning is that it can't see the named `label` inside the data template. The custom combobox class shows up fine but the combobox items do not show up. Is there a way to prevent this issue so that the control can more easily be used?

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <local:RCTLabel x:Name="label" VerticalOffset="-1" Height="10" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="UseRemapColor" TargetName="label" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

The resulting warning in another assembly

[image]

Edit: I should also mention I'm setting the style with the contenttemplate of the comboBoxitem within the resources of the comboBox style. Is this the correct location to set it?

```
<Style.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource RCTComboBoxItemStyle}"/>
</Style.Resources>
```

Comment: It must be the setter in the data trigger not finding a target named `label`. Have you tried setting the trigger on the label itself?

Comment: After doing this I get a new error where elements within the regular contenttemplate of the comboboxitem style are causing the same warning. I'm having trouble figuring out how to reference the comboboxitem's properties from within setting the styles of the controls in the contenttemplate.